# Resolve conflict with eval() function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, magento-1.9, conflicting-libraries

I am trying to set up the Responsive Menu using `combined.js` a merged library of Jquery Sizzle and jQuery core, it is posted here:

https://pastee.org/erewc

But it's `eval` function conflicts and produces error when I include it in a page having many scripts loaded already like jQuery(smartWizard) and PrototypeJS.

Error produced is as below:

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
$('options_2_2').advaiceContainer = 'options-2-container';$('options_2_2').callb...
```

in `combined.js > line 623`

It's involving eval function so I have no clue how to resolve it. I don't think `jQuery noConflict` will work here, still suggestions are welcome.

Comment: either it should be $('.options_2_2') or $('#options_2_2') depending on whether options_2_2 is a class or an id , thats what i think

Comment: @BhawinParkeria As I already said PrototypeJS is also loaded and used in the page, the code in the error is of Prototypejs in which `$('some')` means element with id 'some'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a temporary fix or permanent solution(time will tell), but I managed to resolve the conflict by putting a condition around the `eval` function call(in combined.js) like below:

```
if(t.indexOf("$('options_") == -1) {
  e.eval.call(e, t)
}
```

As I am sure none of my menu elements have "options_" in their class or id attribute.

So my conflict is resolved for now, but still feel free to post your answers if you have a better and cleaner approach for a permanent solution.